# How to sort table fields in my pyspark code

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to have my table in order id,poperty_name,time and value.

I tred to shuffle all  the combinations.

```
my_row =  parsed1.map(lambda x: {

    "id": (str(x[3]) + ":" + str(x[0]) + ":" +str(x[1])),
    "property_name": x[4],
    "time" : x[1],
    "value": x[2],
})
```

Im keep having order time,id,property_name,value, and I can not see why. Those `x[0,...4]` represents just fields from my JSON object that I'm parsing. And it's all working, all extraction is ok, but order is not. And I need exact orded, because this needs to be written in Cassandra DB.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a select with the order you want:

```
sorted_df = df.select("id", "poperty_name", "time", "value")
```

Answer (score 0):

A `select` statement will only keep certain columns in your dataframe, and drop all others. You're looking for the `sort` statement.

Naturally, I'm assuming that you'll also want to specify the way that a particular dimension is sorted. I've included an additional parameter `desc` so that you can see how (within an sorting statement) you can adjust the way this is performed.

Here is an example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
my_row =  parsed1.map(lambda x: {

    "id": (str(x[3]) + ":" + str(x[0]) + ":" +str(x[1])),
    "property_name": x[4],
    "time" : x[1],
    "value": x[2],
})

sorted_my_row = my_row \
    .sort(col("id"), \
          col("property_name"), \
          col("time").desc(), \
          col("value"))
```